# Por que o plugin CodeView não está realçando as cores?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, froala-editor

Estou utilizando o *plugin* Froala em um `textarea`, desta forma:

```
<textarea name="fDescription" class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
```

E então ativando o *plugin* com jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('textarea').froalaEditor({
        placeholderText: 'Digite os detalhes…',
        language: 'pt_br',
        pluginsEnabled: ['align', 'charCounter', 'codeBeautifier', 'codeView', 'colors', 'entities', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'inlineStyle', 'lineBreaker', 'link', 'lists', 'paragraphFormat', 'paragraphStyle', 'fullscreen', 'image','quote', 'table', 'url', 'video'],
        toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'color', 'undo', 'redo', 'clearFormatting', '|', 'paragraphFormat', 'quote', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent', 'subscript', 'superscript',  '|', 'insertLink', 'insertTable', 'fullscreen', 'html'],
        charCounterMax: -1,
        });
    });
```

Quase tudo funciona como eu quero, entretano  quando eu clico no botão *Code View*, até é mostrado o texto em formato de código, mas não está realçando os elementos com a cor, como é mostrado no [site oficial](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) (cliquem no botão *Code View* para ver).

Poderiam me ajudar a corrigir isso para que seja realçado com cores ao clicar no botão?

---

Essa é a minha ordem de importação de CSS:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/froala_editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

e dos arquivos JavaScript:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/froala_lang.min.js"></script>
```

Vocês podem me ajudar?

Comment: Aparentemente nesse [exemplo](https://codepen.io/Froala/pen/qrgPKx), link do proprio site, [não há realce de cores](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/live-code-preview). Talvez você pudesse integrar as funcionalidades de edição do froala, com a capacidade de realce do [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Faltou você inserir as referências do [Code Mirror](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/code-mirror)

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.3.0/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.3.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
```

Para habilitar o  ***Code View*** com a opção   `toolbarButtons: [ 'html' ]` segue uma nota da [documentação](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#toolbarButtons).

> Alguns dos botões acima exigem um plugin específico. [Aqui está a lista
>    completa de plugins](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/plugins) e os arquivos necessários para cada um deles.
>
> - botão html requer o plugin `codeView`;

Segue um exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byyo8mnd/596/).